# Transformation from inertial/sensor frame to the body frame

Tags: python, rotation, quaternions, rotational-matrices

I'm working with IMU providing me with their orientation to a common Global coordinate system. I have created a segment coordinate system from a static posture with know orientations. I have placed two sensors on the thigh, rotated approx. 90 degrees around global Z and 1 on the pelvis. I need to convert the sensors orientation to the segment CS orientation. And when I measure the angle between pelvis and the Segment CS the result should be the same no matter the which thigh sensor is controlling the segment CS

[image]

Here is what I have for know:

```
q_w_Pelvis = []
q_w_R_Upperarm_medial = []
q_w_R_Upperarm_lateral = []
for i in range(len(q_Pelvis_pq)):
    q_w_Pelvis.append(q_Pelvis_pq[i]*q_start_Pelvis.conjugate )
    q_w_R_Upperarm_medial.append(q_R_Upperarm_medial_pq[i]*q_start_R_Upperarm_medial.conjugate)
    q_w_R_Upperarm_lateral.append(q_R_Upperarm_lateral_pq[i]*q_start_R_Upperarm_lateral.conjugate)


q_segment_Pelvis = []
q_segment_R_Upperarm_medial = []
q_segment_R_Upperarm_lateral = []
for i in range(len(q_Pelvis)):
    q_segment_Pelvis.append(q_segment_start_Pelvis*q_w_Pelvis[i]*q_segment_start_Pelvis.conjugate)
    q_segment_R_Upperarm_medial.append(q_segment_start_R_Upperarm_medial*q_w_R_Upperarm_medial[i]*q_segment_start_R_Upperarm_medial.conjugate)
    q_segment_R_Upperarm_lateral.append(q_segment_start_R_Upperarm_lateral*q_w_R_Upperarm_lateral[i]*q_segment_start_R_Upperarm_lateral.conjugate)
```

Followed by a calculation of Euler angles I know works from previous projekt.

But the result is not correct as the two sensors do not provide me with the same rotation of the segment CS.
[image]